# Why stopped working hydrator after migration zf2->zf3?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I can not understand why stopped working AggregateHydrator if you get it in the mapper factory:

```
$aggregatehydrator = $container->get(AggregateHydrator::class);
```

Empty objects are returned. I tried to debug and PHP is dying (excess memory),  when I try:

```
\Zend\debug\debug::dump($aggregatehydrator);
```

If i get hydrator another way:

```
$tagsHydrator = $container->get(TagsHydrator::class);
$categoryHydrator = $container->get(CategoryHydrator::class);
$postHydrator = $container->get(PostHydrator::class);
$datesHydrator = $container->get(DatesHydrator::class);
$aggregatehydrator = new     \Zend\Hydrator\Aggregate\AggregateHydrator();
$aggregatehydrator->add($postHydrator);
$aggregatehydrator->add($categoryHydrator);
$aggregatehydrator->add($tagsHydrator);
$aggregatehydrator->add($datesHydrator);
```

it works all. The filled objects are returned.

https://bitbucket.org/mad-max/blog-note3/overview

```
class AggregateHydratorFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $aggregatehydrator = new AggregateHydrator();

        $tagsHydrator = $container->get(TagsHydrator::class);
        $categoryHydrator = $container->get(CategoryHydrator::class);
        $postHydrator = $container->get(PostHydrator::class);
        $datesHydrator = $container->get(DatesHydrator::class);


        $aggregatehydrator->add($postHydrator);
        $aggregatehydrator->add($categoryHydrator);
        $aggregatehydrator->add($tagsHydrator);
        $aggregatehydrator->add($datesHydrator);

        return $aggregatehydrator;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add the code for `AggregateHydrator` factory.

Comment: So the problem is that your server runs out of memory when doing `\Zend\debug\debug::dump($aggregatehydrator);`. Maybe you shouldn't do that then? Why are you dumping a hydrator instance in the first place?

Comment: Because i tried to debug in order to understand why it did not work. This string is absent in real.

Answer (score 0):

I added in AggregateHydratorFactory:

```
    $aggregatehydrator = new AggregateHydrator();
    $aggregatehydrator->setEventManager($container->get('EventManager'));
```

The answer is here:
https://github.com/zendframework/zend-hydrator/issues/40